# compact XSLT code to drop N number of tags if all are null

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my input xml:

```
<root>
   <node1/>
   <node2/>
   <node3/>
   <node4/>
   <othertags/>
</root>
```

The output must be:

```
<root>
   <othertags/>
</root>
```

if any of the 4 nodes isn't null then none of the tags must be dropped.

example:

```
<root>
   <node1/>
   <node2/>
   <node3/>
   <node4>sample_text</node4>
   <othertags/>
</root>
```

Then the output must be same as input xml.

```
<root>
   <node1/>
   <node2/>
   <node3/>
   <node4>sample_text</node4>
   <othertags/>
</root>
```

This is the XSL code I have designed ::

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/root/node1[.='' and ../node2/.='' and ../node3/.='' and ../node4/.='']
             |/root/node2[.='' and ../node1/.='' and ../node3/.='' and ../node4/.='']
             |/root/node3[.='' and ../node1/.='' and ../node2/.='' and ../node4/.='']
             |/root/node4[.='' and ../node1/.='' and ../node2/.='' and ../node3/.='']"/>
```

As you can see the code requires more effort and becomes more bulky as the number of nodes increase. Is there any alternative way to overcome this bottleneck?

Comment: A good one (+1). I come up forward with a more precise and optimized solution. Also, this kind of task can be conveniently done (even in the case of hundreds of different nodes (N >= 100) ) using FXSL. Look for the continuation...  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried (untested)

```
<xsl:template match="node1|node2|node3|node4">
  <xsl:if test="
    (preceding-sibling::*|.|following-sibling::*)[
      self::node1 or self::node2 or self::node3 or self::node4
    ][.!='']
  ">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: ya.. there is one flaw, I have fixed it .. As I don't have 2000 points I can't edit the post, pls do it by urself, => Replace if statement by, <xsl:if test=".!='' or (
    (preceding-sibling::*|following-sibling::*)[
      self::node1 or self::node2 or self::node3 or self::node4
    ][.!=''])
  ">

Comment: reason :: your code tests only the sibling-nodes values of a particular node whether they are null, so had to add `.='' or` to test the value of self .. thanks for the helpful answer :-)

Comment: @infant programmer Note the . at the start of Tomalak's expression, this tests self as well as the siblings. I get the same result from both versions of the test.

Comment: @infant: Yes I have edited it. My hope was you would not yet have tried it out. ;-) I've made it a little more obvious (and logical) now by placing the dot in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Mode "filter-those-nodes" checks the condition, and "not-those-nodes" removes the unwanted nodes. Unfiltered nodes will match one of the modeless apply-templates as if we just said '` inside the 'root' template.

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="filter-those-nodes"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="filter-those-nodes">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="'' = concat(node1, node2, node3, node4)">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="filter-those-nodes"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node1 | node2 | node3 | node4" mode="not-those-nodes">
    <!-- filtered out -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="not-those-nodes">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @Lachlan-Roche, hi, sorry but in this case, its even more bottleneck kind of thing to follow hierarchical approach. because, these set of nodes appear in many different places. And also usage of <template match="*"> doesn't allow usage of anyother templates .. I have more than 15 templates meant for different jobs.

Answer (score 0):

**A more precise and optimized solution**:

**I. "Regular" XSLT 1.0**

```
 <xsl:variable name="vNotAllEmpty" select=
  "/*/*
      [self::node1|self::node2|self::node3|self::node4]
        [not(. = '')]

  "/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="indent">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "/*/*/node1|/*/*/node2|/*/*/node3|/*/*/node4">
   <xsl:if test="$vNotAllEmpty">
     <xsl:call-template name="indent"/>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

1. **Why more precise**? Because the specific templates matches only `node{N}` nodes that are children of the top element.
2. **Why more efficient**? Because the test deciding whether to process the `node{N}` nodes is performed only once, vs. once per node occurence.

**II. Using FXSL**

The **[FXSL library](http://fxsl.sf.net)** has convenient templates/functions to find out whether or not all or some nodes in a node-set are true (or a condition applied on them is true).

**For this problem the most suitable such FXSL template is `someTrue`.** Here is the complete transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:import href="someTrue.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vallNodes" select=
     "/*/*[starts-with(name(), 'node')]"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vNotAllEmpty">
     <xsl:call-template name="someTrue">
       <xsl:with-param name="pList"
          select="$vallNodes"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="indent">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:variable name="visInspectedNode" select=
    "count(.|$vallNodes) = count($vallNodes)"/>
   <xsl:if test=
      "not($visInspectedNode)
      or
        ($visInspectedNode and string($vNotAllEmpty))
      ">
      <xsl:call-template name="indent"/>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note the following**:

1. The nodes to be processed (vontained in `$vallNodes`) may be hundreds and thousands.
2. The solution is highly extensible. We can test if all or some nodes satisfy a specified condition, using respectively, the FXSL templates `allTrueP` and `someTrueP`.
3. The logic of scanning all nodes and accumulating the truth value is canned in these templates and you never code this logic -- hence no additional time wasted and no possibility to commit errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="/root/node()[name()='node1' or name()='node2' or name()='node3' or name()='node4']
[../node1/.='' and ../node2/.='' and ../node3/.='' and ../node4/.='']"/>
```

Comment: Good, but what if you have many hundreds of nodes and the node-set is constructed dynamically? The FXSL solution works OK in this case, too.